How can I help our Fittonia fill up, get more bushy? It's all hollow looking with long individule stems
It is 3 to 4 yrs old and has been in same pot I bought it in

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As a professional gardener with many years of experience, I can offer practical advice to help your Fittonia (also known as the nerve plant) become more bushy and fuller.
Here are some critical steps you can follow:

Pruning

Regular pruning is one of the most effective ways to encourage your Fittonia to become bushier. By pinching back the growing tips of the stems, you can promote the growth of new branches.
Here’s how to do it:
Use clean, sharp scissors or pruners: Sterilize your tools to prevent infection.
Pinch off the tips: Trim each stem's top 1-2 inches. This will encourage the plant to generate new growth from the nodes below the cut.
Proper Watering
Fittonias thrive in consistently moist soil but don’t like sitting in water. Overwatering can lead to root rot, while underwatering can cause the plant to wilt.
Here’s a balanced approach:
Water regularly: Keep the soil evenly moist but not soggy. Check the top inch of soil; if it feels dry, it’s time to water.
Use a well-draining potting mix: This helps prevent water from accumulating at the roots.
Humidity and Environment
Fittonias love high humidity and indirect light. Ensuring the right environment will help your plant flourish.
Maintain high humidity: You can mist the plant regularly or place it on a humidity tray. A humidifier can also be beneficial if you live in an arid area.
Provide bright, indirect light: Avoid direct sunlight, which can scorch the leaves. A spot with filtered light or partial shade is ideal.
Feeding
Regular feeding during the growing season can also help your Fittonia become fuller and more vigorous:
Use a balanced, water-soluble fertilizer: Feed your plant every 4-6 weeks during the spring and summer. Dilute the fertilizer to half the recommended strength to avoid over-fertilizing, which can damage the roots.
Repotting
If your Fittonia has outgrown its current pot, repotting can give it more space to grow and improve overall health:
Choose a slightly larger pot: Ensure it has drainage holes to prevent waterlogging.
Refresh the potting mix: Use a high-quality, well-draining potting soil. This provides fresh nutrients and better aeration for the roots.
